# How do I convert two vectors into a bounding box with 8 vertices?

Tags: vector

I created two vectors named bboxmin and bboxmax using the functions 
vector3 
`applymin_xyz()` and vector3 
`applymax_xyz()`.

How do I convert them to 8 vertices,so I can test cull with them?

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. What technology do you use?

Answer (score 6):

For an axis-aligned bounding box represented by a minimum and maximum corner, you can extract six pieces of information, `xMin`, `yMin`, `zMin`, `xMax`, `yMax`, `zMax`.

Given those, you can construct your eight vertices as all combinations of the min and max values for each component:

```
{ xMin, yMin, zMin },
{ xMin, yMin, zMax },
{ xMin, yMax, zMin },
{ xMin, yMax, zMax },
{ xMax, yMin, zMin },
{ xMax, yMin, zMax },
{ xMax, yMax, zMin },
{ xMax, yMax, zMax },
```

Of course, normally you would not do this conversion to a polyhedron, but instead work with separating axes or possibly the plane equations. You may want to consult Christer Ericson's [Real-Time Collision Detection](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/) book and the [table of intersection methods](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) from Real-Time Rendering.